# How can I fix Protocol can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements error

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift-protocols

I understand this questions has been asked many times, however I am struggling to understand how this can be attributed to my scenario.

I'm hoping someone can break this down for me so I may understand the issue and how to fix.

I have a protocol

```
protocol HTTPClientProtocol: class {
    associatedtype T: EndpointProtocol
    associatedtype U: Codable

    var task: URLSessionDataTask { get set }
    var session: SessionProtocol { get }
    var request: URLRequest? { get }

    func call(method: HTTPMethod, endpoint: T, urlParams: [String: String], bodyParams: [String: String], queryParams: [String: String]) -> Promise<U>
    .......
}
```

And a class I use

```
class HTTPClient<T: EndpointProtocol, U: Codable>: HTTPClientProtocol {
    var task: URLSessionDataTask = URLSessionDataTask()
    var session: SessionProtocol = URLSession.shared
    var request: URLRequest?

    func call(method: HTTPMethod, endpoint: T, urlParams: [String: String], bodyParams: [String: String], queryParams: [String: String]) -> Promise<U> {
        return Promise<U> { seal in
            request = try? createRequest(
                service: endpoint.service,
                path: createRoute(path: endpoint.path, urlParams: urlParams),
                bodyParams: bodyParams,
                queryParams: queryParams,
                isFastPatch: method == .JSONPATCH
            )
   .......
}
```

I am trying to instantiate this as follows

```
struct RecognitionService: RecognitionServiceProtocol {


    lazy var httpClient: HTTPClientProtocol = HTTPClient<FeedsEndpoint, Recognition>()

}
```

But I get the error

> Protocol 'HTTPClientProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint
>   because it has Self or associated type requirements

Is the only solution to make the `call` func generic instead of the class?

I'm unsure how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
func call<T: EndpointProtocol>(method: HTTPMethod, endpoint: T, urlParams: [String: String], bodyParams: [String: String], queryParams: [String: String]) -> Promise<U>
```

now  Swift has enough information to know how you plan to use endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
struct RecognitionService: RecognitionServiceProtocol {

  let httpClient: HTTPClientProtocol = HTTPClient<FeedsEndpoint, Recognition>()

}
```